# how to see complete output in visual c++ 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2008, visual-c++-2008-express

my program's output is very big, like I run for loop for 100 times, displaying 5-6 lines every time. Problem is, when I run output, it displays only last 20-25 results. Is it possible to all of the results at once?

Comment: Why not simply log your output to a file or database or something?

Comment: is it not possible to see output without logging it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a console app or a GUI app? If console, you can make the screen buffer size bigger - select the Properties menu item from the console icon in the upper left corner and go to Layout tab, change the Height in the Screen Buffer size to something much larger.

Comment: i *think* he means the Output window in the VS IDE.